# Vuetify v-img automatically grows to size of container, not the size of its src

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

The Vuetify [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/#height) on `v-img` states:

> v-img will automatically grow to the size of its src, preserving the correct aspect ratio. You can limit this with the height and max-height props.

However, it's growing to the full size of the container or `max-height`, whichever is smaller. It is not growing to the size of its source — the image src in the following example is 256x256.

Example:
https://codepen.io/nullism/pen/bGWVreK

Is this a bug with Veutify, an issue with the documentation, or am I missing some property?

Thanks very much in advance!

**Update**: Looks like a regular `<img/>` tag works as expected: https://codepen.io/nullism/pen/OJmyjvw

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you want the image to be smaller than 256 x 256 in size, in that case the properties are added max-width="256" max-heigth="256"

```
    <d id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-img max-width="256" max-heigth="256"
              src="https://www.redditstatic.com/icon.png"
            ></v-img>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'd like the image to autoscale. I was able to solve this by _not_ using Vuetify's provided `v-img` as it doesn't work for scaling inside of a container like a standard `<img />` tag does.